# How to format output in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've got a span like this

```
<span>${bean.name}</span>
```

and it returns something like  John Brown

how can i format it so it shows like BROWN, John in jstl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to the point, you want to apply the following modifications on the `String`:

1. Split in 2 parts on whitespace (what to do if there are more whitespaces?)
2. Show the 2nd part of the split in uppercased flavor.
3. Show a comma and then a space.
4. Show the 1st part of the split.

This is all doable with [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html).

1. `<c:set var="parts" value="${fn:split(bean.name, ' ')}" />`
2. `${fn:toUpperCase(parts[1])}`
3. `,`
4. `${parts[0]}`

Summarized:

```
<c:set var="parts" value="${fn:split(bean.name, ' ')}" />
${fn:toUpperCase(parts[1])}, ${parts[0]}
```

You've only another problem when the name contains more than one space.